# Why isn't keyword DateField.input_formats recognized in django 1.0.2 and Python 2.5?

Tags: python, django

With django 1.0.2 and Python 2.5, when I use the keyword `DateField.input_formats`, I get the error that `__init__()` got an unexpected keyword argument `'input_formats'`. When I look in the `__init__` file, I don't see `input_formats` as one of the acceptable keyword arguments.

I thought that `input_formats` had been around long enough that it should be in there. Is the `input_formats` keyword not supported in this configuration? If not, how can I acquire an updated `__init__` that does support it? Thank you.

As suggested in the comment, I have added code below. I suspect the problem is that I am confusing the `DateField` form and `DateField` model, but I would be pleased if someone could confirm that.

```
from django.db import models

class Payment(models.Model):
    date_paid = models.DateField(blank=True, db_index=True, input_formats=['%m/%d/%y'])
```

Comment: -1: No Code provided with the question.  Odds are good that you've messed up models.DateField and forms.DateField.  But with no code, no one can help you.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Having looked at the docs, like you suspected, [models.DateField](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#datefield) doesn't have an input_formats, but [forms.DateField](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/fields/#datefield) does (as does forms.DateTimeField)